# Check if shown (randomised) image is the same as last (randomised) image (jQuery & JavaScript )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

(Before anything, you should know that my JS skills are very basic)

I'm trying to make my own "rapid sorting" from the game "BrainWars" on smartphones.

Basically what it should do is:

Step 1: randomise one of the 3 pictures available and show the image.
Step 2: if this image is the same as the last one ( do something )
Step 3: If this image is NOT the same as the last one ( do something else )

For now , I have a folder named "images" with 3 png's inside it.
So far I have this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var random_images_array = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png'];
    var lastImage = "";

    function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
      path = path || 'images/'; // Default path hier opgeven
      var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgAr.length);
      var img = imgAr[num];
      var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
      document.write(imgStr);
      document.close();
    }


    $(function() {
      $('#btn').click(function() {
        getRandomImage(random_images_array, 'images/');

        setTimeout(function() {
          getRandomImage(random_images_array, 'images/');
        }, 2000);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>


<body>
  <button id="btn">GO</button>
</body>

</html>
```

How can one achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a lastImage variable...

```
var random_images_array = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png'];
var lastImage="";
```

Then:

```
var img = imgAr[num];
if (img==lastImage) {do  something}
else {lastImage=img; ... document.write(imgStr);}
```

Comment: Yes. but how to determine what the last image ( or its value/variable ) is?
My goal is to show an image at the start, and with some kind of timeout function ( after 5 seconds ) showing the next image... Now, How could one know what the last image ( or its value/variable ) was  in this case?

Comment: Because you've stored the last image value in lastImage (lastImage=img)!